# How do I use argument twice in a function in J?

Tags: arrays, j, tacit-programming, apl

I want to write prime function for purposes of learning J.
So far I've come up with this:

```
=&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y
```

It's working great except that I should store number in `y` variable.

```
   y=.5       
   =&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y NB. prime cheker
1
   y=.13       
   =&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y NB. prime cheker
1
   y=.14
   =&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y NB. prime cheker
0
```

How do I write a function that works what takes argument? i.e. `f 13` -> `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [define](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm) a verb using `: 3`.

```
f =: 3 :'=&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y'
f 5
1
f 13
1
f 10
0
```

When using `: 3`, `y` always refers to the right hand argument of the verb.

If you want to define a dyadic verb, use `: 4` and `x` for the left argument.

Btw, you can set the value of a variable anywhere:

```
   =&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y=.5
   1
   =&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y=.10
   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find the [Defining Verbs](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Guides/Defining%20Verbs) Guide on the J Wiki useful.

As has already been mentioned you can take your sentence and define it as a verb using the following syntax:

```
isPrime0=: 3 : '=&0+/(=&0)(2+i.(-&2)y)|y'
```

However it is probably more natural to write it like this:

```
isPrime1=: 3 : '0 = (+/ 0 = (2 + i. y - 2) | y)'
```

You could also define a tacit version (doesn't refer to the arguments) like any of the following:

```
isPrime2=: 0 = [: +/ 0 = ] |~ 2 + [: i. 2 -~ ]
isPrime3=: 0 = [: +/ 0 = ] |~ 2 + i.@:-&2        NB. replace train with verb composed using conjunctions
isPrime4=: 0 = [: +/ 0 = ] |~ i.&.(-&2)          NB. use Under to re-add the 2 after Integers
isPrime5=: 0 -.@e. i.&.(-&2) | ]                 NB. check no zero in result
```

Comment: One other simple tacit version is: `1 { [: /:~ i. | ]` but works for integers > 2. Eg. `((1 { [: /:~ i. | ])"0 #]) 3+i.25`, gives `3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23`